# Is is possible to set a default PDO fetch mode?

Tags: php, pdo

Before I retrieve data I always have to type:

```
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

In the interest of making my code more readable it would be great if I could set a default mode somewhere....

Thanks!

**Edit**. I was originally hoping I could add PDO:FETCH_OBJ to the [setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) code I run when I connect to the DB, but that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
$connection = new PDO($connection_string);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Answer (score 33):

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) a fourth, optional, parameter can hold a key=>value array of driver-specific connection options.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name;port=$db_port;charset=utf8mb4";
$driver_options = [
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
];               
$dbh = new PDO( $dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $driver_options );
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Comment: Yes of course !
Just to add that PDO allow to set a list of parameter. So using the array $options you can easily add more input to customise you Query output ...

Comment: This looks great as it is at this point in time. Also it works for PDO::FETCH_NAME and PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ,... etc.