# stdClass when fetch as OBJ by default

Tags: php, fetch, stdclass

I prefer use $obj->value than $array['value'], so i used

```
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

The problem is when i do a simple req :

```
 public function getUsers()
  {
    return $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetch();
  }
```

It return me a stdClass and i can't get users list. (Or i don't know how, but it look weird, I never saw stdClass before).

So with FETCH_OBJ attribute I've got:

```
$list = $users->getUsers();
var_dump($list); // object(stdClass)#4 (6)[...]
```

Without FETCH_OBJ attribute I've got: (With same code)

```
array(12)[...]
```

And I have 2 rows 6 cols so this line give me error: (not error, but not what I want)

```
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Do you know why ?
Is there another way to set FETCH_OBJ as default ?

I just wanna make *fetch()* instead _fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)_...

Thanks.

Edit: I don't own database class.
I'm doing like this:
database.php

```
try {
    $database = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projet', 'root', '');
    $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
    die ("error mysql: $e");
  }
```

UserManager class :

```
class UserManager
{
  private $conn;

  public function __construct(\PDO $database)
  {
    $this->conn = $database;
  }

  public function getUsers()
  {
    return $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetch();
  }

}
```

And in any file i want to use getUsers():

```
$users = new UserManager($database);
$list = $users->getUsers();
```

Comment: *"I never saw stdClass before"* `stdClass` is PHP's *generic* object, what you'd get if you did `(object) array()`. In the case of returning the object from the query, the stdClass would have the column names as attributes; e.g. `$obj->id`

Comment: Ok I see. And why it return me only one row from my users table ?
Call to undefined method stdClass::fetch()

Comment: @PierreDemailly because you are using `PDO::fetch()` in your getUsers method. Use `fetchAll()` if you want to return all users at once. You will have an array of StdClass. Look at `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` if you want to have instance of specific class. If you want to keep going like `while $row = $q->fetch()`, maybe your method should return the statement. You can also "cheat" and use `yield` instead of `return` so you would use it like `foreach (getUsers() as $user) {...}`

Comment: @Zyigh THANKS! My bad i wonder again why i used fetch() and didn't see it lmao

Comment: @PierreDemailly It happens all the time. I have a routine to avoid this kind of mistakes (especially in bigger algorithms). I talk to the caretaker, and I explain to him what I'm doing very precisely in a manner he can understand. It really helps to understand more clearly your goals, your problems and how to resolve it. When you explain line by line, you realize that what you are saying make no sense or doesn't fit what is writtent. Don't forget to mark your question as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StdClass is PHP generic object (as said in the comments).

I'll try to answer to other questions you ask in comments too.

You're only getting one result because you are using `fetch` which give *the next result*, false when there isn't any result left. You have a few options for that :

- Yield

  Using a generator. It means that you "pause" the method, and you have to call it like an Iterable. For example :

  ```
  public function getUsers()
  {
    yield $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetch();
  }
  ```

  Would be use like :

  ```
  foreach ($userManager->getUsers() as $user) {
      // $user is a row of your database
  }
  ```

Be carefull with this because it can let your database connection open.

- FetchAll

  It returns all the results of your query at once in an array. Note that if you have only one result, you will have an array of one element. For this one you would do :

  ```
   public function getUsers()
   {
       return $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetchAll();
   }
   //...
   $users = $userManager->getUsers();
   foreach ($users as $user) {
       // your code
   }
  ```

Also not that if you want an instance of a User class you've made, you can use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`. You will find the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Hope it helps !

Small edit in case it's not quite clear, you can specify the format as ::fetch() argument such as :

```
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // will return results as associative array even if you specified FETCH_OBJ in your constructor
}
```

Comment: changing fetch method to `FETCH_ASSOC` is not answer, How we can use data while `stdClass` exists ?

Comment: @a55 You probably have a different problem than the one the author asked. Also, `FETCH_ASSOC` is not the answer. If you need to deal with objects, you might find everything you need here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setFetchMode` in the query object, like this `$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` And then just `$users = $query->fetch()`. More in the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: I wanna use fetch() for any query.
And i want fetch give me object instead array.
U'are right, but I have to do this on all my queries...

Comment: Take a look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037842/ddg#11037910)

Comment: It's exactly what I did.