# MySQL - how to get multiple results from SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

This code is only displaying one row. How can I show the other rows that are in the MySQL table when I execute one of the queries?
Thank you for anything you can offer! Help is appreciated!

```php
// Display query results in a table
if ($queryresults) {
    $row = $queryresults->fetch_assoc(); // Problem is here or below
    echo "<table> <tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Start Time</th>";
    echo "<th>Duration</th><th>End Time</th>";
    while($row) {
        // Create row of table
        $str = "<tr><td>". $row['name']."</td><td>". $row['starthour'].":";
        $str .= format2($row['startmin'])." ". $row['ampm']."</td><td>". $row['hours'];
        $str .= "h ". format2($row['minutes'])."m</td><td>". $row['endhour'].":";
        $str .= format2($row['endmin'])." ". $row['endampm'] . "</td></tr>";
        echo $str;
        $row = $queryresults->fetch_assoc($queryresults);
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "Error: #".$connection->errno." – ".$connection->error;
}
// Logout of server
$connection->close();
```

Comment: You cannot run multiple queries with query($query).  It is only running $a

Comment: I am pretty confused by this line: $query = (($month != 'All') and ($day != 'All')) ? $a : $b;

Comment: I'm not sure if I can mark this as duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286142/stdclass-when-fetch-as-obj-by-default/51286780#51286780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try:

```
 while ($row = $queryresults->fetch_assoc()) {
 /* do stuff with the $row */
 }
```

And remove every other `$row` assignment. I think there is a mistake in the way you are calling fetch_assoc()

Comment: Looking back on this question from the future, this answer is blindingly obvious from the documentation: `fetch_assoc()` takes no parameters when called with an object, so the last line of the loop was erroneous. I don't know how I didn't spot that then.