# global setting of PDO's setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is is possible to set a default PDO fetch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893858/is-is-possible-to-set-a-default-pdo-fetch-mode)

I have searched the internet and this site and could not find an solution.

Is there a way to apply `$this->query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` globally for all PDO queries? I find myself repeating the line over and over again.

I have tried applying it to the initial `PDO` connection: `$this->connection->setFetchMode()` but that throws an exception.

Comment: Consider the disadvantages of that, your code could be less portable because of the global setting dependency.

Comment: @MrCode - It's "global" to the object / connection he is creating, it's not global for all PDO objects created in the current session. I see no portability issues here.

Comment: Ah, nickb, I didn't couldn't find that! Thank you!

Comment: @nickb I realise the scope. The point I was making is if you are dependency injecting the PDO object into a bunch of code (as should be done), or have it as a singleton, said code won't function if you move it to another environment where the PDO object doesn't have the setting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since 5.2

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You can do this when you first instansiate it as well
new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,DBUSER,DBPASS,
                   array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));