# printing out array value twice / php and pdo

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

i am getting the "$field_value" twice - but why?
normal the structure is: `<id><name><address><email>` but now i get `<id><id><name><name><address><address><email><email>`

here is the code:

```
 <tbody>

        <?php
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM kunden");
        $STH->execute();
        $result = $STH->fetchall();

        foreach($result as $key => $inner_arr) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($inner_arr as $field_name => $field_value) {
                echo "<td>{$field_value}</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        ?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: you have `for each Value of Result and for each Value of InnerArray => print smth` so for each both of them, you have twice more iterations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `fetchMode`:

Default is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, so an array indexed by both column name and number will be returned.

```
$result = $STH->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: [Or set default fetch mode on connection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893858/is-is-possible-to-set-a-default-pdo-fetch-mode)