# PHP PDO return a row twice

Tags: php, sql, pdo

When I use a SELECT query on PDO, i get something like this:

```
Array ( [name] => "name" [0] => "name" )
```

Is there a simple way to avoid the [0] value?

Thanks.

Comment: You can fetch it as object

Comment: [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484294/printing-out-array-value-twice-php-and-pdo

Comment: Yay, thanks a lot. PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is what I need